# how to show mysql provider on mvc (add new cnnection ) dialog

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, database-connection

i have an mvc app
i added all the mysql connectors to the project references
i opened the Package Manager Console and typed "Install-Package    MySql.Data.Entity -Pre", and then pressed Enter

then
i replaced this code in the web.config file

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity"/> 
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
      invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.2.0"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

i also added my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myconn"
    providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    connectionString="[Insert your ConnectionString from Azure here]"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**now when i go to =>Data Connections =>add connection => change

i cant find mysql provider there

what i have to do to add it in the data sorce there???**
thanx for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install MySQL for Visual Studio to get that provider in the available providers list when adding a new data connection.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html

a screenshot from my Visual Studio 2015 : 
[image: a screenshot from my machine]